# (CLOSED) Replacement to Java for downloading file from database

Tags: java, sql, database, download

I'm going to create a program that downloads a file from a database to a clients computer. I don't want to use Java because it'll require the client to have Java installed. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Caway C, and welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question is primarily opinion-based, and will most likely be closed soon.  Don't let that deter you from making a correction to your question and asking again.  You can read more about that here:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use C# or VB.NET, or Python, etc. Any language really.